# I am using a monitor to my notebook, but have problems

Tags: laptop, display, operating-systems

I am using a monitor to my notebook, but have problems, when I am using a extern monitor for my notebook the OS is often slow, why?

Comment: There is no information provided to help here. Is the monitor the same resolution as the laptop?  A big variance here might cause an issue. We do not see OS slowdowns when we add compatible external displays to client laptops.

Comment: No, the resolution are not the same. Thanks! I didn't know resolution could matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to know what is slowing down a computer is monitoring usage in Task manager.
Right click the taskbar and click on task manager, Go to performance tap and check if anything is near 100% when your computer is slow.

My guess is your graphics card is not good enough to run two monitors or the resolution of it, But that shouldn't slow down your PC only your graphics applications.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Linux

Comment: @MiguelSilva I'm not experienced with Linux but try searching for system monitor and see if there is one.

Comment: Ok, I'll do. Thanks!